# override scss variables in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass, vuetify.js

To increase the width of vuetify's v-switch, i want to modify the value of vuetify's scss variable.

vuetify was configured through vue-cli, and the developed code is as follows.

```
// src/assets/css/overrides.scss
$font-size-root: 24px;
$switch-width: 400px;
$switch-track-width: 400px;
```

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: ['vuetify'],
  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: 'source-map',
  },
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      scss: { // 8.0.3
        prependData: `@import "@/assets/css/overrides.scss";`,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

But nothing has changed. What stupid thing am i doing?

ref:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables/
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#css-modules

Comment: As specified [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables/#example-variable-file) you have to place the overrides before the import. `// Variables must come before the import`

Comment: @tao hmm... Is it necessary to import from other places than vue.config.js?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I wasted a lot of time with this problem. But later, I realized it was easy. You don't need to import files or write `loaderOptions` in `vuetify.config.js`.

1. In your `src` folder, create a `scss` folder
2. In your new `src/scss` folder, create a `variables.scss` file

```
 src
├─  scss
|  └─  variables.scss
...
```

The `vuetify-loader` will automatically bootstrap your variables into Vue CLI's compilation process, overwriting the framework defaults. *Following [this documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/#vue-cli-install).*

**Example**

```scss
// projectRoot/src/scss/variables.scss

$font-size-root: 24px;
$switch-width: 400px;
$switch-track-width: 400px;
```

After doing all this, stop your local server and restart with `npm` or `yarn` only once. After these steps, every change you make will appear automatically. So you don't need to restart the development server every change.

Comment: Can I override the local $font-size-root in a component? I tried <style lang="scss" scoped>$...</style>. But thats not working

Comment: Do you want to change the font size in a single component or the entire application? "$font-size-root" changes the font size of all components.

If you want to change the font size in a single component;

Define your ".scss" file in your "app.vue" file. Do not use "scoped". Then define the class "testClass {font-size: ...px;}" in your ".scss" file. Finally, try adding this css class to the element you want to change the font size of.

If this solution doesn't work, write again.

Comment: You don't have to use the "variables.scss" file found in my answer. If you want, you can make this definition in a different ".scss" file. However, if you want to use a different .scss file, you must define the new .scss file you have created in the App.vue file.

Comment: Ah ok. I see I will try thanks

Comment: someone who gets it working with a custom file name? I'm not able to find any example...

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me on Veutify 3:

**Step 1**: Install
[webpack-plugin-vuetify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-plugin-vuetify) or [vite-plugin-vuetify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-vuetify)
then enable it in your bundler configuration.

**Step 2**: On your `vite.config.ts` add
`vuetify({ autoImport: true, styles: { configFile: 'src/scss/settings.scss' } }),`

**Step 3**: create `settings.scss` file on 'src/scss'

**Step 4**: Add settings on `settings.scss` example:

```
@use 'vuetify/settings' with (
    $expansion-panel-text-padding: 0px,
);
```

Restart npm / clear browser if change did not reflect

Comment: Thanks, this is easier to follow than the instructions on the vuetify site - but now it takes ages for Vite to connect each time I run the app