# common btn-border-radius for all buttons

Tags: sass, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am working on a Vue application which needs same radius define for all buttons used in the application.
For now, I have used defined special class and used css:

```
.confirmBtn {
  width: 200px !important;
  height: 40px !important;
  font-size: 16px !important;
  border-radius: 2px !important;
}
```

But I want to set up [Vuetify — A Material Design Framework for Vue.js](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-btn/#sass-btn-border-radius)  default value for border-radius in the preset and remove the use of fault scss variables. I have vuetify.js file in my application.

Please suggest.

Comment: I believe the [documentation](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/) covers this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @yoduh. I have followed this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63887936/override-scss-variables-in-vuetify and it works now